# Construct json object from query with group by / sum

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table which looks like this :

```
ID   CURRENCY    PRICE
1    EUR         100
2    EUR         650
3    USD         90
```

I want to do a query that returns a JSON object formatted like this:
{ "EUR": 750, "USD": 90 }

The value is the sum of each row with the same currency.

I tried to do it with json_object_agg :

```
SELECT
  json_object_agg(currency, SUM(amount)) AS balance
FROM business_balances GROUP BY currency;
```

but I have an sql error :

> ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Any idea how can I do it? :)

Comment: it says you can't `json_object_agg(sum())`

Comment: Your example is incoherent. Your table has the column `PRICE` while your query sums up `amount` and 100 EUR + 650 EUR != 760 EUR.

Comment: @RobinKoch yeah, my bad x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smth like should work:

```
with p as (
  SELECT distinct currency, SUM(amount) over (partition by currency) AS balance
  FROM business_balances
)
SELECT
  json_object_agg(currency, balance)
FROM business_balances GROUP BY currency;
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty like what I was looking for ! Thanks :)

Comment: ... `column "balance" does not exist`

Answer (score 2):

Do the first aggregation (sum) in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT json_object_agg(currency, sum) AS balance
FROM (SELECT currency, sum(amount)
      FROM business_balances GROUP BY currency
     ) as sums;
```